# How can i convert NSDate to NSString ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm receiving date from server as the following format "/Date(1413374176217)/" . I tried this

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]
 NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
 NSLog(@"dateFromString = %@",dateFromString);
```

but doesn't work.

How can I convert it to string?

Comment: @Krishnabhadra i removed the strings from the date to get 1413374176217 at the end.. but after using NSDateFormatter i get null

Comment: Ask yourself:  When you do `NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];` and in the very next line store a new value into `dateFromString`, what happens to that first NSDate instance you created??

Comment: And does your date format string resemble the date you're trying to parse *even a little*??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

```
NSString *actDate = @"/Date(1326067200000)/";
NSString *nDate = [[[[actDate componentsSeparatedByString:@"("] objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@")"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:([nDate doubleValue] / 1000)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string appears to be a unix time stamp with thousandths of a second.
Assuming you LITERALLY meant you get that string back from your server you could do this.

```
NSString * serverData = @"/Date(1413374176217)/";

NSString *timeString = [[serverData componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

double timeStamp = [timeString doubleValue];

NSTimeInterval interval = timeStamp/1000;
NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString * dateString =[formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the the value being returned is in milliseconds from the epoch and not in seconds. `1413374176217` is about 1000 times larger then it should be to be the current Unix timeStamp. Try something like this

```
- (NSDate *)dateFromStringInMilliseconds:(NSString *)millisecondsStr
{
    // Get our string value in seconds instead of milliseconds
    NSTimeInterval unixTimestamp = [millisecondsStr doubleValue] / 1000.0;
    // Convert to an actual date.
    NSDate *actualDateVal = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimestamp];
    // For good measure you could throw in an assert here if you wanted.
    // NSAssert(actualDateVal, @"actualDateVal equals nil this should never happen");
    /* If you don't have the assert you could just do the below instead of creating actualDateVal.
     * return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:unixTimestamp];
     */
    return actualDateVal;
}
```

then you can just call it doing `NSDate *date = [self dateFromStringInMilliseconds:@"1413374176217"];`